# Delete found row except some cells in that row

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code in a form with a delete button.

I have Columns A, B, C, D, E, F with data and need to delete data in columns A, B, C. Which row is deleted is based on ListBox1 value.

I don't know how use `Find`, `Row`, `Delete` (except D, E, F) together in this case.

```
 Sheets("ORDERS").Range("A:A").Find(ListBox1.Text).Activate        
 sil = ActiveCell.Row         
 Sheets("ORDERS").Rows(sil).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the code below:

```
Dim FindRng As range

Set FindRng = Sheets("ORDERS").Range("A:A").Find(ListBox1.Text)

If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then '<--  successful find
    Sheets("ORDERS").Range("A" & FindRng.Row & ":C" & FindRng.Row).ClearContents
Else '<-- find was unsuccessful
    MsgBox "Didn't find " & ListBox1.Text & " in worksheet 'ORDERS' "
End If
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I need. Thank you